# flask-socketio not handling events

Tags: python, socket.io, flask-socketio, python-socketio

Hi i am unable to handle socketio event from a python client to a python server(flask socket-io). Both are connecting. but events are not handled

Notes on environement:
My client is on a Hyper V guest. i added a virtual adapter. host ip is 10.10.10.1

Server:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
sio = SocketIO(app,logger=True, engineio_logger=True)
sio.run(app,host='10.10.10.1',port=5555)

@sio.on("event")
def ev_handle(data):
    emit("NO")
    print("printme")
```

Client:

```
sio=socketio.Client(logger=True, engineio_logger=True)
sio.connect("http://10.10.10.1:5555")
while True:
    input("say something to emit event\n")
    sio.emit("event",data="bob")
```

output for client:

[image: output for client]

output for server:

[image: server output]

tried solution so far:

- different event name, tried on connect , tried to use @sio.event
- tried writing into a file to see if print was the problem
  My code seems reasonable. idk why it is not working. firewall does not seem to be the issue as PING and PONG are being sent/received

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is looking for a fix, you need to implement the handlers before you call run:

```py
app = Flask(__name__)
sio = SocketIO(app,logger=True, engineio_logger=True)

@sio.on("event")
def ev_handle(data):
    emit("NO")
    print("printme")

sio.run(app,host='10.10.10.1',port=5555)
```